# TF.exe workspace remapping and switching

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, teamcity, tf-cli

Folks,

I am trying to unshelve and then download a single file using TF.exe command line utility. But i keep facing problems.

This is being done from teamcity interface. There a better way of doing this ?

**To unshelve**

```
if "%ShelvesetName%"=="" exit /b 0
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" workspaces /server:%tfscollection% /owner:%uDeploy_Username%
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" unshelve "%ShelvesetName%" /recursive /noprompt /login:%uDeploy_Username%,%tfspassword%
```

To get a single file from a different Root url in TFS

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" workspaces /server:%tfscollection% /owner:%uDeploy_Username%
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" workfold /map "%TFS_BRANCH_SPECIAL%" "%wspath%"
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" get /v:LnewLabel
```

Comment: If you just want to unshevle and download a single using TF.exe command? Why you need to remapping and switching the workspace? Did you want to unshelve to a  to different location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to unshelve to a different location/branch. You could try to use **[tfs power tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)**.

Define your path in cmd with the TFPT. And then, from there, you go to the destination folder or workspace where you want to unshelve your code.

```
1. c:\>path = %path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 201x Power Tools

2. cd c:\[some location]\"destination workspace"

3. tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:"$/ProjectName/Branch" /target:"$/ProjectName/Targetbranch" "My Shelveset Name"
```

If you want to download to an different local workspace, just unshelve it to the corresponding sever path/branch, then download the branch from server to local workspace.

More details you can refer this blog: [Move Shelveset to a Different Branch in TFS](http://benjii.me/2014/04/move-shelveset-to-different-branch-in-tfs/)